# Accelerometer Sensor

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope, tilt-sensor

I am a newbie in android.
Just wondered how gyroscope works in android . Is it any hardware that is mounted inside or what exactly it is ?
Also, would like to know if gyroscope and accelerometer sensor are in anyway related ??

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We generally like questions to be about [specific programming problems](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). If you are, for instance, having trouble with your gyroscope-related application, we'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

As for your first question, Google "gyro MEMS". For example, you will find [An Overview of MEMS Inertial Sensing Technology](http://www.sensorsmag.com/sensors/acceleration-vibration/an-overview-mems-inertial-sensing-technology-970).

Your second question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5541875/341970).

Answer (score 1):

Gyroscopes is the device which measures the rate(angular speed) change and Accelerometer measure the change in speed in x,y and z directions.

These devices has internal mechanism(made up of capacitors,filters, ADC components and an interface(I2c, spi)) to carry these analog outputs to digital world where they are interpreted by the software(sensor fusion libraries).

In the device (phone or tablet) they may or may not be present as a separate module(chip) but sure they are connected to the MCU of the Phone either directly or Via some target MCU(to which they are connected via interface like I2C or SPI).

No Gyroscopes and Accelerometers are not related in any way but their data when combined together on the basis of certain algorithms(of what sensor fusion libraries are made up of) gives the orientation of the the device and may help to flip the screen owing to their output.
-Rp