# Is it possible to combine an Accelerometer and Digital Compass to get a fine Gyroscope?

Tags: android, accelerometer, compass-geolocation, gyroscope

I want to make an app that need to use Gyroscope Sensor

However, due to cheap android phone didn't provide this sensor but it still have accelerometer and digital-compass in itself.

As far as I know.. Since, accelerometer can detect 3 axis of our phone. When compare to Gyroscope, only the thing they lack is they can't detect if user rotate their phone without changing their pose. That's why I need to use digital compass to get the north direction to solve this problem.

So, I would like to know is it possible to just use only these 2 sensors to make a gyroscope sensor work-like? Anyone ever try? Is it actually work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear *why* your app needs gyroscopes. I assume that you want to track the orientation of the phone.

You can track the phone orientation reasonably well with the accelerometer, compass and a low-pass filter. It lags a bit but it works, I have impleneted that for the Shimmer platform. See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5541875/341970) with the link to a demonstration video.

Comment: I would like to make AR Application (eg. put some obj model to one place by see through camera )

Comment: AR - Augmented Reality, maybe voforia from Qualcomm

Comment: OK, I have no idea what this buzzword is. If you want to track the orientation then my answer holds. If you want to do something else then please explain what it is.